# Oracle Entity Framework NUMBER(3,0) getting Cast to NUMBER(10,0)

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework-6

I am using Entity Framework for data access with an Oracle Database.  Many of the tables in the database have a column that is a NUMBER(3, 0) field.  When I reverse engineer the database, these get generated in the entity as an INT property.

Because they are an int, when I run queries against the database, many of the fields in the database get cast to a NUMBER(10,0) even though they are a NUMBER(3,0).

For example in a where clause:

> AND (( CAST( "Extent2"."PARTICIPANT_DBI" AS num ber(10, 0))) =
>   :p__linq__8))

I believe that this prevents the index from being used correctly.

What is the best way to fix this issue?